# PHP 7.0 installed, but version doesn't change

Tags: php

I'm trying to install PHP 7.0, which works. But when I check my `php -v` in the cmd, it still says 5.5.36.

I tried it via php-liip, homebrew, install manually and via cmd. Nothing works. When I change version of PHP in MAMP (which I work with to try and install composer in a directory, that I need PHP 5.6 or higher for) i still doesn't matter.

Comment: Try to restart the web server.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP 5.5 you're seeing was installed by Apple and is a default on your computer. It was installed at `/usr/bin/php`.

All of the installers you've used *will not overwrite Apple's default installation* - they will instead opt to create their own directories or use `/usr/local/bin/` instead (thus the PHP interrupter would be installed at `/usr/local/bin/php`). In other words, you almost certainly have multiple `php`'s ready to use right now. The next thing you need to do is tell **bash** (the default terminal/cmd on a Mac) to use the newly installed PHP interrupter.

When you run `$ php` on your command line, bash checks for an executable file on each of paths stored in the `PATH` environment variable. Once it finds one, it decides that *that* executable is the one you're looking for and runs that program. As of now, it's finding Apple's PHP 5.5 before it finds your fresh install of PHP 7.0 - assuming it finds PHP 7.0 at all.

You can fix this by updating `PATH` to check wherever PHP 7 is installed first. Instructions to do so can be found on SuperUser.StackExchange:

[How should I set the PATH variable on my Mac so the Homebrew-installed tools are found?](https://superuser.com/a/533708/491597)

Answer (score 0):

To change php version in Ubuntu, try to use this comand

```
sudo update-alternatives --config php
```

and then select version what you need